# Como probar cual de estos códigos es mas eficiente?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimización

Estoy resolviendo algunos ejercicios y comparando mis resultados con los de otros. Me encontré dos lineas muy similares que resuelven el problema pero quisiera saber cual de ellos esta mejor optimizado.

Estas son las lineas:

```
return a1.filter(a => a2.some(b => b.includes(a))).sort();
```

```
return  a1.filter(x=> a2.join(' ').includes(x)).sort()
```

Ambas lineas resuelven el problema pero,  como saber cual de las dos es mas eficiente?

---

**+INFO**

En general lo que hace el código es tomar dos arreglos. El arreglo `a1` debe retornar solo palabras que sean subcadenas de cualquier integrante de `a2`

Comment: para saber cual es más optimo debes ponerlo a prueba en tiempo de ejecución, recursos del sistema...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haciendo una [prueba rápida en JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/test-para-pregunta-322698-en-esso-1), el segundo algoritmo es un 50% más lento que el primero:

[image: resultados de JSPerf]

Pero quizás sea por los ejemplos que he usado como muestra (algo simple para ser sincero y además está ordenada):

```
let a1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"];
let a2 = ["a","c","e","g","i","k","m","o","q"];
```

Lo que hacen los dos algoritmos:

- En el primer código:

  1. [`some()` devolverá verdadero en cuanto la función pasada como *callback* devuelva verdadero](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some). Esto quiere decir que no tiene que atravesar todos los elementos del array en cada pasada para ejecutar el `includes()`. En cuanto encuentra 1, se acabó.
  2. El array resultante se ordenará.
- En el segundo algoritmo:

  1. Para cada elemento del array `a1`, se hace una unión del array `a2` (con [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)) y se comprueba si el elemento existe en la cadena resultante con `includes()`.
  2. El array resultante se ordenará.

Ignorando el `sort`, que sería el mismo, tendría sentido que el primer algoritmo fuese (considerablemente) más rápido porque realiza menos operaciones y operaciones menos costosas:

- No tiene que atravesar el array completo en cada iteración (aunque poniéndonos en el peor de los casos, sí tendría)
- Las manipulaciones de cadenas son más costosa... ¡y se realizan en cada iteración!

Basándonos en esto, y por hacer más pruebas, lo que podrías hacer es mover la creación de la cadena a fuera del filtro. De ese modo sólo se ejecutará una vez (no necesitas que se ejecute más) y te ahorrarás numerosas operaciones:

```
const cadena = a2.join(' ');
const a3 = a1.filter(x => cadena.includes(x)).sort();
```

He añadido ese ejemplo al JSPerf y es el que obtiene mejores resultados de los tres (aunque hay que considerar que las cadenas están ordenadas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Nota: llevo sin hacer esto mucho tiempo y puede que me esté equivocando en algo de lo que pongo

Explicación teórica:

- El orden de complejidad del primer algoritmo es O(N<sup>2</sup>) porque en el peor de los casos se atraviesa `a2` (de tamaño N) una vez por cada elemento de `a1` (de tamaño N), lo que resulta en N * N = N<sup>2</sup>.
- El orden de complejidad del segundo algoritmo es O(N<sup>2</sup>) también. `a2` (de tamaño N) se atraviesa entero cada vez que hay que generar la cadena (ignorando que es una operación más costosa) y eso ocurre una vez por cada elemento de `a1` (de tamaño N), lo que resulta en N * N = N<sup>2</sup>.
- El orden de complejidad del tercer algoritmo sería O(N). La cadena se genera una sola vez, por lo que `a1` se atraviesa una sola vez (N) y luego `a2` se atraviesa una vez (N) comparando cada elemento con la cadena, lo que deja N + N = 2N ~ N.

¿Por qué el primer algoritmo es entonces mucho más rápido que el segundo incluso cuando tienen el mismo orden de complejidad? Por dos motivos:

- La muestra no era la adecuada: está ordenada lo que favorece el uso de `some` en este caso; y
- Realiza operaciones menos caras: las operaciones de I/O y trabajo con cadenas son generalmente más costosas.

Comment: Esta excelente. Me tome la libertad de agregar una muestra real del ejercicio a la prueba que realizaste. Y las pruebas dan un resultado similar.  Muchas gracias. Solo no me queda claro que significa `~` este símbolo.

Comment: @Angel Al calcular el orden de complejidad de un algoritmo, se ignoran los factores constantes. Por eso un orden 2N es equivalente (`~`) a N.

Comment: Pero, lo dicho en la respuesta, llevo sin ver complejidad algorítmica (en teoría) más de una década. Así que toma esa última parte con prudencia, por si he dicho alguna barbaridad.

Comment: Jajaja seré prudente. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.